# CS cart addon development, do specific task after each order placed, extra store data, custom URL for specific task inside addon

Tags: e-commerce, cs-cart

I am trying to develop a new add-on for cs cart.

I need some help for following matters:

- I want to use a hook that will run my code from my addon for my own task. I want to use a hook that will be triggered each time when a new order is placed, using either cash or paypal payment. Which hook should I use so that no order will miss this hook? I want to send order details to a third party API when order placed by customer. For cash order, instantly, and for paypal, order when IPN comes.
- For multi store license, how can I put store specific custom settings/configuration in my addon? I mean each store will have different custom settings to identify by my addon.
- I need a URL that will trigger/run some code from my addon that will do some db update and send notification only. How could I do that in my addon?

Please, if anyone could help me. At least if you could give me some link of documentation or tutorial, then it will be enough because I am not seeing these things in cs cart documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Well I can answer 2 of the 3 questions.

So you have multi store licenses, each store has its own ID, therefore you could use the hook `company_id`.

- Just add `{if}` and after that your code. (or you just apply this to the necessary locations of your code. (you can also use `{foreach}` to make it somewhat "automated".

About the URL,

- you could setup a custom [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) Job, please visit the `cscart` documentation for this.